# How do I push a "Large File" and push .gitattributes, too? remote: error: File file.psd is 705.45 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit

Tags: github, version-control, large-files

I have Git LFS enabled on my Github account, and should be able to handle arbitrarily large files for this.

However, even after modifying my .gitattributes to track the large file, I still had errors when I attempted to push a file larger than 100MB, as described in the following command line history log:

http://0bin.net/paste/dZlE60XjuTyr2eTb#0XizLswk02II9Ub9Nou4gKS4K469vvIYsosQNCyxROo << attempt with OS file.

The most pertinent error seems to be related to this:

> remote: error: File file.psd is 705.45 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I tried again, this time specifically tracking that file, and including the .gitattributes in the commit, but still received the same error, as logged at the target of the following link:

http://0bin.net/paste/OpQGS+UxtGLdkrSj#-fSDATfAbp6V5UbsbBy8+okIpp+/HFE0RITcVvP0Pnp << attempt with OS file.

This seems like an error that might end up cropping up in the future for professional programmers who use GitHub, which is why I posted it.

Do I need to add this to the .gitattributes of the remote manually before I push a commit?

How do I get the remote to accept the modified .gitattributes AND the large file?

Comment: // , Please comment before downvoting. Also, might it be worthwhile to add a git-lfs tag?

Comment: // , I'm currently having a go at this after editing .gitattributes directly on the remote.

Comment: // , So far, I have followed the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/ to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try editing and committing the .gitattributes on the remote repository to add the following:

```
file.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -crlf
```

Substitute the target file that you want to push as part of your commit for the `file.psd` part of the above line.

Pull from the remote, and try again.

That might work.